# Approximation of tempered distribution.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, partial-derivative

Here I met a problem from Vasy's PDE textbook:

> Show that every $u\in\mathcal{S'}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can be approximated by elements of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, i.e. show that there exist $f_j\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\iota_{f_{j}}\to u$ in $\mathcal{S'}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I cannot work out with the given hint in the book, or in his exam:
http://web.stanford.edu/class/math173/173-f.pdf

(this was a final test in winter 2016, so please do not doubt about plagiarism)

Another question is, are there any related books or material to cover such question?

Comment: The idea of the hint is that to obtain an element of $\mathcal{S}$ you have to be sufficiently decreasing at $\infty$ and sufficiently regular i.e sufficiently decreasing at $\infty$ in Fourier space. To obtain this you "truncate" $u$ by multiplying by a cut-off function both in "normal" space and in Fourier space. The main point is then to show that this intuition can be translated into a rigorous proof.

Comment: The problem of mine is mainly on the technical part of the proof，I cannot find proper way to derive the given bound in the hint.